# how to set an environment variable with pwd in a docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I would like to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable based on my working directory using my Dockerfile. I have tried using `ENV $PWD/some/subpath` but when I inspect the container later using `docker exec mycontainer bash -c "env"` it shows up as `/some/subpath` rather than `/my/working/dir/some/subpath` however I also see that `PWD` is defined as `/my/working/dir/` as I would expect it to be. so why is using `$PWD` in my Dockerfile not substituting the way I am expecting it to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44452854/pwd-is-not-set-in-env-instruction-in-a-dockerfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44453513/4676641), `$PWD` is a special environment variable set when running a shell. Unlike `RUN` commands, `ENV` commands do not create a shell so `PWD` is never set.

To get the value of `PWD` at build time, you could instead use a build-arg and pass in `$PWD` in the build command.

You'd do this in your Dockerfile like this:

```
# dockerfile
ARG working_directory
ENV $working_directory/some/subpath
```

and build like this:

```sh
docker build --build-arg "working_directory=$PWD" .
```